# Getting initial pickerview row with exactly value

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I have UIPickerView with following data:

```
var pickerData = [1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 45, 60, 90, 120, 180, 270, 300]
```

I try to save selected row:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        var customTime = pickerData[timePicker.selectedRowInComponent(0)]
        currentRow = timePicker.selectedRowInComponent(0)
        meditationTime = customTime // it will be saved in Parse (as PFObject)
    }
```

And I need to get initial row with saved value:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        timePicker.selectRow(currentRow, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
}
```

But I have "0" into `currentRow` first loading, and required value every next time.

Comment: where currentRow is decleared?

Comment: picker view method has the row constant you can access the selected row.  currentRow it is probably = 0 when viewDidAppear.

Comment: @Shoaib currentRow is public variable